# Shared Preferences in WebView

Tags: android

I want to limit how many songs a user can download in my FREE app. The download is executed everytime a user clicks on a link that ends with /download/. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get this to work with shared preferences. When testing I was able to download a file at least 5 times so it obviously didn't work. Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
else if (url.startsWith("http://xxxxxx.com/songs2/Music%20Promotion/Download/")) {
            prefs2 = getSharedPreferences("downloadlimit", 0);
            editor = prefs2.edit();
            long launch_count = prefs2.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
            editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

            if (launch_count >= 2) {                    
                    showRateDialog(getApplicationContext(), editor);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call `editor.commit();` to ensure that your changes are saved.  See here for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: one more question, can the users clear the shared preferences by clearing the application data?

Comment: yes.  clearing application data brings the app back to the state it started in when installed.